# isGranted not working on custom role names

Tags: symfony

I don't use native role names like `ROLE_USER`. Instead, because using custom ACL solution, I use role names simply like `USER` or `ADMIN`.

The roles are set in native way and Symfony debug toolbar shows this under the Security Token section:

```
Roles   

[▼
  "ADMIN"
  "USER"
]
```

But now, if I use the native `isGranted('ADMIN')` it always returns false.
How to fix this issue? I know I can implement custom permission check model (and did), but it would be nice to use the default one, which works for example also in Twig templates (the `is_granted` function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the default voter supports only role with prefix ROLE_. See in constructor of \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\RoleVoter.
But you can [create a new custom voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#creating-the-custom-voter) and check for roles by yourself. Just make a "copy" of default RoleVoter and leave the prefix out.

Comment: I understand. Many thanks for your advice. Sadly, I can't upvote because of low points.

Comment: @JakubD Not only the default voter supports only prefixed roles, but roles *are required* to start with `ROLE_`. See first bullet point [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles)

Comment: @msg you mean this: "Every role must start with ROLE_ (otherwise, things won't work as expected)" ... but this is applied to default RoleVoter, isn't it? So with a custom RoleVoter it would work I think.

Comment: Yes, but that's the section on creating custom Roles, not Voters, so I'd err on the side of caution and take the advice of prefixing all roles with `ROLE_`

Comment: Note it says: "This is a nice default, but you can do whatever you want to determine which roles a user should have. Here are a few **guidelines**... ". Still probably a good idea to follow it for most cases, but I'm not 100% sure that it's a **requirement**.